# if(NSOrderedAscending == result) can someone explain this

Tags: ios, ios4, nsstring, compare

I read Apple's documentation and sometimes it feels like Apple's documentation is too complicated on purpose.

```
NSStringCompareOptions  compareOptions = NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;

if(NSOrderedAscending == result)
```

does it mean that the strings do not match?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`NSOrderedAscending` means: *The left operand is smaller than the right operand.* `NSOrderedDescending` means the opposite: *The left operand is greater than the right operand.*

Equality is represented by `NSOrderedSame`: *The two operands are equal.*

Comment: What does smaller mean for strings? ASCII value is smaller? or length of string is smaller? thats what confuses me

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: String comparisons use "lexical ordering" (or what a grade-school kid would call alphabetical order). You need to be thinking beyond "ASCII", though - NSStrings can include non-ASCII chars like å or ç. In many cases you'll want to be using a comparison method like `-localizedCompare:`, which uses the appropriate comparison/ordering for the current locale. (For example, does 'å' come before or after 'á', or should they be considered "equal"? The localized compare methods know about that kind of stuff so you don't have to.)